# Terraform: nested for loop from yaml

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I am trying to run nested `for` loop on terraform.
I have the following Yaml file:

```
Employees:
  - Department:
    - Dev:
      - name: "danielf"
        role: developer
        details:
          email  : danielf@example.com
          firstname  : daniel
          lastname   : folsik
      - name: "johnb"
        role: developer
        details:
          email  : johnb@example.com
          firstname  : john
          lastname   : belk
    - Ops:
      - name: "benol"
        role: devops
        details:
          email  : benol@example.com
          firstname  : ben
          lastname   : olkin
      - name: "pauld"
        role: devops
        details:
          email  : pauld@example.com
          firstname  : paul
          lastname   : dempler
```

I am using `locals` to get the yaml data:

```
locals {
  ou_config = yamldecode(file("employees.yaml"))
}
```

I want to run into the list of objects on "Dev" and "Ops" lists using for_each.
for example, I want to run on the "Dev" list to get the following list of objects in the first iteration:

```
[
   {
      key   = "email"
      value = "danielf@example.com"
    },
    {
      key   = "firstname"
      value = "daniel"
    },
    {
      key   = "lastname"
      value = "folskin"
    }
  ]
```

The next run on the for_each will be:

```
[
   {
      key   = "email"
      value = "johnb@example.com"
    },
    {
      key   = "firstname"
      value = "john"
    },
    {
      key   = "lastname"
      value = "belk"
    }
  ]
```

etc.
**How can I do it on terraform?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you are trying to extract is the `details` portion of that yaml file ...

Here is what I would do to get all:

```
locals {
  ou_config = yamldecode(file("employees.yaml"))

  expanded_names = flatten([
    for e in local.ou_config.Employees : [
        for d in e.Department : [
            for key, person in d : [
                for key, value in person : [
                    value.details
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ])
}

output "test" {
    value = local.expanded_names
}
```

---

And if we want to filter we add an `if key == "Dev"`

```
locals {
  ou_config = yamldecode(file("employees.yaml"))

  expanded_names = flatten([
    for e in local.ou_config.Employees : [
        for d in e.Department : [
            for key, person in d : [
                for key, value in person : [
                    value.details
                ]
            ] if key == "Dev"
        ]
    ]
  ])
}

output "test" {
    value = local.expanded_names
}
```

A terraform plan on that will look like:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = [
      + {
          + email     = "danielf@example.com"
          + firstname = "daniel"
          + lastname  = "folsik"
        },
      + {
          + email     = "johnb@example.com"
          + firstname = "john"
          + lastname  = "belk"
        },
    ]
```

That format should be easier to loop in the final resource than the key value you suggested